# GCP App Engine with Serverless VPC Connector doesn't work when app is deployed using mvn deploy

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have a pipeline that runs on gitlab, it builds and deploys code to App Engine, so far, so good. Recently we encoutered the need to route requests to internal hosts, which we found could be solved using  a Serverless VPC Connector.

We created the connector, referenced it on app.yaml as per gcp docs, deployed the code using gcloud deploy in order to test, this worked perfectly. But, the same code, when deployed using mvn deploy from the gitlab pipeline, doesn't talk to the internal hosts. I suspect mvn deploy doesn't parse the app.yaml file correctly or at all.

Has anyone encountered this situation before?

Comment: If you can confirm this and not seeing any actionable messages on your end, I suggest creating a [new issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues) through the official repo.

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?